# lwip buffer in microplaze application

Tags: c, ethernet, lwip, microblaze

Simply i check and get data send to my microplaze  by cheking payload of my pbuff at recieve callback function , and it works where i can see that microplaze echoes back my messages but when i tried to  print them fro mmicroplaze to terminal(using printf() in c code) something strange happened here is the print out :

```
sent "a"  printed: "a";
sent "aa"  printed: "aa";
sent "aaa"  printed: "aaa";
sent "aaaa" printed: "aaaa
|Ì¥ìk…"
```

what is that and why and it happens to anything more than 3 chars .. why is that ? any ideas ?

I am using sprtan3a with microblaze processor of 16bit bus and 4mb ram .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because Characters are not terminated